Conditions for Catholic dissolution of marriage when both have been baptized
I read in the Wikipedia article on the Indissolubility of Marriage in the Catholic church that:

a natural marriage, even if consummated, can be dissolved by the Church when to do so favours the maintenance of the faith on the part of a Christian, cases of what has been called Pauline privilege and Petrine privilege. In these cases, which require intervention by the Holy See, the Church admits real divorce, the actual dissolution of a valid marriage, as distinct from the granting by merely human power of a divorce that, according to Catholic theology, does not really dissolve the marriage bond.

Reading the linked articles on Pauline and Petrine privilege, a big condition is whether either party was correctly baptized at the time the marriage was validly contracted.
But what if one spouse became so opposed to the other's practice of the Catholic faith, let's say due to acting on some fundamentalistic Protestant tenet that calls a Catholic to be a non-Christian?  How about when one spouse renounced his/her Christian faith altogether and became a hindrance to the Catholic spouse's practice of Catholicism?
Are there any conditions where a consumated marriage between two validly baptized Christians (one of them Catholic) can be dissolved?  For the sake of this question, the marriage was registered in the parish of the Catholic party as a sacramental marriage.

No, a valid marriage between two validly baptized Christians cannot be dissolved for any reason. This is clear from canon law, 1141, which says "A marriage that is ratum et consummatum can be dissolved by no human power and by no cause, except death."
An invalid marriage between two baptized Catholics or two baptized Christians, however, can be annulled. This involves a tribunal appointed by the competent authority (the bishop) to investigate whether the marriage has a nullity, a condition at the time of the vows that renders the marriage invalid. An annulment is a conclusion that a marriage has never existed, not a dissolution of a marriage which did exist.
In case one party is causing life for the other to become difficult due to the rejection of the Catholic faith on the part of the one, the Catholic party is called to carry their cross, to love their spouse, and to pray for them. In cases where there is domestic abuse, the Catholic party may seek a civil divorce, without intent to reconcile, without sin, but they cannot remarry. They are married to their spouse until death.

"can be dissolved by no human power" - does it mean that it is impossible (i.e., there is no man with authority to do that) or that it is never licit to do so (i.e., the Pope has the authority to do that, but it is never permissible)?

@rafa11111 it's impossible
